# Can Using Git over SSH be distinguished from normal SSH traffic?

Tags: server, ssh, iptables, git

So, I set up my iptables configuration so that repeated attempts to SSH into my private server cause a blacklist.

```
# iptables -N SSH
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j SSH
# iptables -A SSH -m recent --name sshbf --rttl --rcheck --hitcount 3 --seconds 10 -j DROP
# iptables -A SSH -m recent --name sshbf --rttl --rcheck --hitcount 4 --seconds 1800 -j DROP 
# iptables -A SSH -m recent --name sshbf --set -j ACCEPT
```

Now, my git repository is also hosted on this server, and it's set to work over ssh, as

```
git@myserver:/path/to/repo.repo.git
```

Would there be a way to amend the iptables rules above such using the git account doesn't trigger the hitcount rules. It would not be fun to try to commit a few times bc of a lot of coding progress and then be locked out of the server for a half hour.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using key based authentication along with a passphrase with SSH for security instead of the complicated iptables setup you are using. Just allow port 22 and your server will still be safe.

http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2008/02/20/public-key-authentication-for-ssh-made-easy/

It is going to be difficult to craft the firewall rules in such a way to guarantee your git commits are not going to shut down your access since the firewall can't tell the difference.